# Unable to Save a PDF ....Click the Save button for the Save As dialog box. VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, sendmessage, savefiledialog

```
My Code:

    Sub login()
          Dim IE As Object
          Dim HTMLDoc As Object, HTMLDoc2 As Object, HTMLDoc3 As Object, HTMLDoc4 As Object, HTMLDoc5 As Object
          Dim objCollection As Object
          Dim intChoice As Integer
          Dim strPath As String
            
          Const navOpenInNewTab = &H800
          Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
          IE.Visible = True
          IE.Navigate "https://www.abcd.com/CWRWeb/displayMemberLogin.do"
    ...............
    
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: Loop
          Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:0:03"))
          IE.Navigate "https://www.abcd.com/CWRWeb/OnlineStmtResultsPremDis.do" 'Final PDF
          Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:0:03"))
          Set HTMLDoc5 = IE.document
                Application.SendKeys "+^{S}" 'Save Key ShortCut
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:0:03"))
        
      'Finding the Save As Dialog Box
      
      timeout = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")
      Do
      hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Save As")
      DoEvents
      Sleep 200
      Loop Until hWnd Or Now > timeout
     
   
      If hWnd Then
      hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, 0, "Button", "&Save")
      End If
      
      If hWnd Then
      SetForegroundWindow (hWnd)
      Sleep 600
      SendMessage hWnd, BM_CLICK, 0, 0
      End If
      
      End Sub
```

My declaration in another module is:

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)


Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" _
                                  Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, _
                                  ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
                                  
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                                                           ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
                                                           
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long) As LongPtr
                                                           
                                                           
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As LongPtr
                                                           
                                                           
Public Declare PtrSafe Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
                                                           
                                                           
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    


    Public Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
    Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
    Public Const WM_GETTEXT = &HD
    Public Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = &HE
    
    Public Const VK_KEYDOWN = &H0
    Public Const VK_KEYUP = &H2
    Public Const VK_CONTROL = &H11
```

I debugged and found that I am able to get the same Hwnd for FindWindow and FindWindowEx but the SendMessage function gives a run time error453:
Cant find DLL entry point SendMessage in User32

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a Find Window could work?

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
 'Declare this at the top of the module!

... your routine until the save as dialog is shown
Call iDetectScreen("Save As","Save As not found!")
... After detection what should do (Personally I'd do a send keys Enter)
...
Sub iDetectScreen(iScreen As String, iWriteErr As Integer)
Do Until lHnd1 > 0
    lHnd1 = FindWindow(vbNullString, iScreen)
    If i < 5 Then
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    i = i + 1
    Else
    msgbox iWriteErr,vbCritical
    'window save didn't show 5 secs after supposed to
End Sub
```

***EDIT:***
This should work. Tested in x64 2013, fit to your needs.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
 'Declare this at the top of the module!
 Sub iDetectScreen(iScreen As String, iWriteErr As String)
Do Until lHnd1 > 0
    lHnd1 = FindWindow(vbNullString, iScreen)
    If i < 5 Then
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    i = i + 1
    Else
    MsgBox iWriteErr, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
    'window save didn't show 5 secs after supposed to
    End If
    Loop
End Sub
Sub SendEnter()
Call iDetectScreen("Save As", "Save As not found!")
AppActivate "Save As"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Application.SendKeys ("~")
End Sub
```

In your sub

```
...
Set HTMLDoc5 = IE.document
                Application.SendKeys "+^{S}" 'Save Key ShortCut
call SendEnter
...
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to click on the save button of the SAVEAS dialog box?

Comment: Have you tired the above sub/integration in your code? Do you know about sendkeys? Application.SendKeys({ENTER})

Comment: The code gives an error for declaration....mine is 64bit system. I used sendkey to get the Save As dialog box

Comment: Yeah, you need (after that sendkeys that opens the save as ) a. FindTheWindow  ([google how to declare it in x64](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp)) Hint: just change to " Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow..."  b. Probably an AppActivate of that Window c) Sendkeys again to "Save"

Comment: I edited the code above....Now I am getting runtime error...whats wrong?

Comment: Got it the error is in declaration: Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As LongPtr.......................Alias was missing

Comment: I don't know why you added that much to the second, check my updated answer

Comment: Quick Question : If I want to edit the folder name or filename can I use the : hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, 0, "ComboBoxEx32", vbNullString)

Comment: Findwindow just works for me to find the window and then do appactivate of that, provided code -as shown- works for the original question ;)